# segmentation fault understanding Valgrind output

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I have written a code which generates financial analysis for 1500 unlisted firms using their 20 quarters financial statements. The code mostly uses rollapply function to calculate rolling quarterly averages and sums. However, its performance has been erratic. While most of the time the code works just fine but some times it gives segmentation faults. If I re-run the code after some time it runs without issues.

After repeated efforts I have not been able to track down the error. I have used valgrind to locate the error. The code returned following output after the segmentation fault.

```
==24224== Invalid read of size 8
==24224==    at 0x4F3C030: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F3ED9B: CONS_NR (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F38146: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F11F89: Rf_applyClosure (in/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F43617: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F43CA3: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F019FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0CF6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F1249C: Rf_applyClosure (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D065: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F10955: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D38F: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==  Address 0x91635f0 is 4,448 bytes inside a block of size 4,608 free'd
==24224==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24224==    by 0x5011332: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x500C208: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x5008710: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F2AEEC: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F012D8: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0CF6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F1249C: Rf_applyClosure (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D065: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0EFB8: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D466: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F10955: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==
==24224== Invalid read of size 1
==24224==    at 0x4F3C034: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F3ED9B: CONS_NR (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F38146: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F11F89: Rf_applyClosure (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F43617: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F43CA3: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F019FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0CF6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F1249C: Rf_applyClosure (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D065: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F10955: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D38F: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==  Address 0x91635e3 is 4,435 bytes inside a block of size 4,608 free'd
==24224==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24224==    by 0x5011332: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x500C208: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x5008710: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F2AEEC: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F012D8: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0CF6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F1249C: Rf_applyClosure (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D065: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0EFB8: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F0D466: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==24224==    by 0x4F10955: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
```

What does this output means? what is libR.so?

Is there any function similar to rollapply?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sorry for not giving the code. It's an 800 line code and I don't know where the problem is.

I have got two traceback() output for two different runs.

run 1

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0xe1, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: NROW(data)
2: (function (i, offsets, data, ...) {    if (is.null(offsets))         return(NULL)    posns <- i + offsets    ix <- posns >= 1 & posns <= NROW(data)    if (partial < 0) {        if (all(ix))             FUN(data[posns], ...)    }    else if (sum(ix) >= partial) {        FUN(data[replace(posns, !ix, 0)], ...)    }})(dots[[1L]][[20L]], dots[[2L]][[20L]], data = c(52.52, 55.51, 49.83, 47.21, 49.16, 44.55, 50.82, 51.46, 57.29, 48.24, 46.99, 44.23, 45.46, 41.31, 44.75, 51.7, 61.86, 63.34, 61.04, 63.42, 66.04, 69.76, 84.45, 95.53, 96.73, 97.51, 94.57, 84.34, 84.62, 77.97, 78.25, 77.04, 72.13, 86.34, 114.31, 112.92, 120.43, 126.21, 116.4, 118.45))
3: mapply(f, seq_along(time(data)), width, MoreArgs = list(data = coredata(data),     ...), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
4: rollapply.zoo(zoo(data), ...)
5: rollapply(zoo(data), ...)
6: coredata(rollapply(zoo(data), ...))
7: rollapply.default(NetSalesOrrevenues, 4, FUN = sum, fill = NA,     align = "right")
8: rollapply(NetSalesOrrevenues, 4, FUN = sum, fill = NA, align = "right")
aborting ...
```

this is from a different run of same code

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
 1: ORDER.default(order.by)
 2: ORDER(order.by)
 3: zoo(do.call("c", dat), index(data), attr(data, "frequency"))
 4: rollapply.zoo(zoo(data), ...)
 5: rollapply(zoo(data), ...)
 6: coredata(rollapply(zoo(data), ...))
 7: rollapply.default(temp_NetSalesOrRevenues, 4, FUN = sum, fill = NA,     align = "right")
 8: rollapply(temp_NetSalesOrRevenues, 4, FUN = sum, fill = NA, align = "right")
aborting ...
```

I am using the rollapply function to calculate ltm sales. The data used is normal sales data.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of all 800 lines, you could provide the one line of code that dumps, and sample of the data you are giving as arguments.

Comment: the problem is I don't know where the issue is. Perhaps you can tell me some way to narrow down in the code, That would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in the debugger? `browser()` is your friend here. (If it's failing within a specific function, try `debug(functionname)` and then run it.) If it's a long-running function, I tend to put in debugging statements (`message(...)`) and see the last message before the dump. I then go back into the code and insert a call to `browser()` just before the dump, perhaps `if (...) browser()` if it breaks some late in a loop.

Comment: What's about `traceback()`?

Comment: @UweBlock I have added the traceback() output.